# Attaching kerberos to apache httpclient in java

Tags: httpclient, kerberos

I have kerberos token with me and I want to attach it to a my `HttpClient` request in java.  I know this is how we attach basic credentials. I want to attach kerberos token instead:

```java
client.getState().setCredentials( new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY), 
    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password") );
```

Answer (score 0):

The entire GSS-API code is currently under completely [rewrite](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1625). Meanwhile (not tested), you can pass your `GSSCredential` with a `KerberosCredentials` object.